# Elasticsearch find minimum price based on filter

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregation

I would like to fetch the minimum price from elasticsearch based on some filter like city_id and model_id. So can it be possible for without making price nested document.

i'm trying this query but won't work please help.

```
POST /myindex/mytype
{
  "aggs": {
    "min_price": {
      "min": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to remove one occurence of `"aggs"` and it will work.

Comment: @val i have remove the aggs but not working.

Comment: Please update your question and define "not working"

Comment: @Val min price is possible without making nested document.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by nested document in this context. Please show a few sample document which are in your index.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right you want the minimum priced document based of filter, if so your query should be like:

```
POST /myindex/mytype/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "price": "asc"
  },
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
              "city_id": "123"

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but how we find the minimum price in this query.

Comment: curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty=1" -d'
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
              "city_id": "123"

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  "aggregations": {
    "minimum_price": {
      "min": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}' this works for me.